# how to speed up writing a large string into a file in python

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a 1 Gb input txt file (1 million lines * 10 columns) and I am using python to process this input to get some calculated information and add each information (out of 1 M lines) into a string, and eventually save it. I tried to run my script, but realized the process got slower and slower as the string got bigger. I am wondering is it possible to append each line into the output and remove the previous buffered line to reduce the memory usage? Thank you. An example of codes:

```
import pandas as pd

# main_df.txt has more than 1 million lines and 10 columns
main_df = pd.read_csv('main_df.txt')

"""
processing main_df into new_df, but new_df still has 1 M lines in the end
"""

sum_df = ''
# I'm guessing sum_df gets super big here as it goes, which uses up memory and slows the process . 
# I have a bunch of complex loops, to simplify, I will just make an example for one single loop:
for i in range(len(new_df)):
    sum_df += new_df.loc[i, 1] + '\t' + new_df.loc[i, 3] + '\t' + new_df.loc[i, 5] + '\n'

with open('out.txt', 'w') as w:
    w.write(sum_df)
```

Comment: why not use a generator expression instead? also why do can't you just write the df straight to a text file? `df.to_csv`

Comment: @Datanovice sorry for the confusion, I have rephrased my question above. There are several loops to get new lines that will be added into `sum_df `, so the above for loop is just one simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what your goal is here, but a few things might help. Here is an example df.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({0:np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=(10)),
                       1:np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=(10)),
                       2:np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=(10)),
                       3:np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=(10)),
                       4:np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=(10)),
                       5:np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=(10)),
                       6:np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=(10))})

print(new_df)

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   z   k   o   m   s   k   w
1   x   g   k   k   h   b   v
2   o   y   m   r   g   l   r
3   i   n   m   q   o   j   h
4   r   d   s   r   s   p   s
5   t   o   d   w   e   b   a
6   t   z   w   y   q   s   n
7   r   r   d   x   b   s   s
8   g   v   h   m   w   c   l
9   r   v   y   i   w   i   z
```

Your code outputs:

```
sum_df = '' # this is a string, not a df

for i in range(len(new_df)):
    sum_df += new_df.loc[i, 1] + '\t' + new_df.loc[i, 3] + '\t' + new_df.loc[i, 5] + '\n'

print(sum_df)



i   k   z
x   g   o
y   l   x
g   s   l
p   h   e
u   s   v
r   u   l
m   j   e
q   k   f
d   p   b
```

I'm not really sure what your other loops are supposed to do, but the one in your example looks like it's just taking columns 1, 3, and 5. So rather than a for loop, you could do something like this.

```
sum_df = new_df[[1,3,5]]
print(sum_df)

   1  3  5
0  k  m  k
1  g  k  b
2  y  r  l
3  n  q  j
4  d  r  p
5  o  w  b
6  z  y  s
7  r  x  s
8  v  m  c
9  v  i  i
```

Then save it to a .txt with something like this.

```
sum_df.to_csv('new_df.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t')
```

Generally speaking you want to avoid looping over dfs. If you need to do something more complex than the example you can use pd.apply() to apply a custom function along an axis of the df. If you must loop over the df, df.itertuples or df.iterrows() are preferable to for loops as they use a generator like mentioned by Datanovice's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out...

```
w = open('out.txt', 'a')
for i in range(len(new_df)):
    sum_df = new_df.loc[i, 1] + '\t' + new_df.loc[i, 3] + '\t' + new_df.loc[i, 5] + '\n'
    w.write(sum_df)
w.close()
```